# Android - Splash screen flashes quickly and then immediately goes black on some tablets

Tags: android, themes, manifest, splash-screen

I am currently developing an app with a splash screen, and for some reason, on some tablets (specifically on an Asus Transformer Pad Infinity TF700T running Android 4.2.1 Jelly Bean), the splash screen just flashes quickly and then immediately goes black.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pink.jazz"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.pink.jazz.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pink.jazz.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my theme for the Splash activity:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Here is my code to move between the splash activity and the main activity (called by onCreate):

```
void navigateToMainScreen() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi! I've checked your code on Nexus 5 and it's okay! Perhaps, your problem is in somewhere else. Could you give your project?

Comment: The problem is that it only occurs on some tablets.  So far the only tablet that I tested that has this problem is the Asus Transformer Pad Infinity TF700T with Android 4.2.1 Jelly Bean.

Comment: Does your splash contain transparent background?

Comment: Also, I had similar bug on old samsung phone that doesn't support selector animation. Do you have an animated selectors?